# react native run-ios fails

Tags: react-native

This was working just Friday. No change in code. (Other than doing a time machine backup in Mac).

But since today `react-native run-ios` just does not seem to be working. The simulator comes up, but then the usual `loading http://localhost:8081` does not show up any more. No errors or any indication on why this is failing. The simulator shows my App in home screen. Double clicking it just brings up and the app seems to crash immediately.

But `react-native run-android` works fine.

Am not sure where to even begin debugging this. (Am new to whole app development).

A few observations,

1. when I run `npm start` and then run `react-native run-ios`, it
   usually "detects" that packager is running and skips launchPackager command, but today its not the case, the launchPackager opens regardless of whether a package is already running (Happens both with `run-android` and `run-ios`
2. There is usually below lines once the app begins loading. But today they only show up when I run `react-native run-android`

   8:43:46 PM]  find dependencies
   transformed 728/728 (100%)
   [8:43:46 PM]    find dependencies (553ms)
   [8:43:46 PM]    request:/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false (661ms)

And when I run react-native logs-ios, I get the below errors

```
Sep 12 20:53:15 sseshac-in-la com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.ADE00521-C04E-4EC5-8BE2-FE729523A0B9.launchd_sim[3812] (UIKitApplication:org.reactjs.native.example.X[0x3f02][4589]) <Notice>: Service exited due to signal: Abort trap: 6
Sep 12 20:53:15 sseshac-in-la assertiond[3832] <Error>: assertion failed: 15G31 13E230: assertiond + 15801 [3C808658-78EC-3950-A264-79A64E0E463B]: 0x1
Sep 12 20:53:15 sseshac-in-la Unknown[3832] <Error>:
Sep 12 20:53:15 sseshac-in-la SpringBoard[3828] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:org.reactjs.native.example.X[0x3f02]' crashed.
Sep 12 20:53:15 sseshac-in-la assertiond[3832] <Error>: assertion failed: 15G31 13E230: assertiond + 15801 [3C808658-78EC-3950-A264-79A64E0E463B]: 0x1
Sep 12 20:53:15 sseshac-in-la Unknown[3832] <Error>:
Sep 12 20:53:15 sseshac-in-la assertiond[3832] <Warning>: notify_suspend_pid() failed with error 7
Sep 12 20:53:15 sseshac-in-la assertiond[3832] <Error>: assertion failed: 15G31 13E230: assertiond + 15801 [3C808658-78EC-3950-A264-79A64E0E463B]: 0x1
Sep 12 20:53:15 sseshac-in-la Unknown[3832] <Error>:
Sep 12 20:53:15 sseshac-in-la SpringBoard[3828] <Warning>: Reply Error: Connection interrupted 
Sep 12 20:58:36 sseshac-in-la routined[3817] <Error>: CoreLocation: Error occurred while trying to retrieve motion state update: CMErrorDomain Code:104
```

**UPDATE:**
I think the root cause seems to below error

```
<Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'bundleURL must be non-nil when not implementing loadSourceForBridge'
```

Note that I am using React native 0.32. I understood that now it "detects" rather than hardcoding the bundleUrl. If someone can throw light on where this "detection" is, will be helpful

Comment: Seems related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9218. No resolution as yet.

Answer (score 3):

Problem turned out to be I was missing an entry in /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

I still don't have any clue why it would work before. But that solved it

Comment: Same here. Had been messing around with my hosts file for alternate reasons, came back to find the rn project broken. Simply restoring my /private/etc/hosts solved the problem

Comment: this is freaking life saving answer mate .. phew :| :| thank you

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have problem with the packager make sure your modules all built you can check by opening 
http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true 
in the browser after the build you will get the error